# What are valid payment-method-tokens?

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm trying to create a credit card and therefore I need to call `paymentMethodNone()`. According to the documentation I can

> Use PaymentMethod.create() to create a payment method for an existing customer:

```java
// It's not clear what A_PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN has to be
Result<PaymentMethodNonce> result = bt.paymentMethodNonce()
                                      .create("A_PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN");

String nonceFromTheClient = result.getTarget().getNonce();
Customer customer = customerResult.getTarget();

PaymentMethodRequest paymentMethodRequest = new PaymentMethodRequest()
        .customerId(customer.getId())
        .paymentMethodNonce(nonceFromTheClient);

Result<? extends PaymentMethod> paymentMethodResult = bt.paymentMethod()
                                                        .create(paymentMethodRequest);

PaymentMethod paymentMethod = paymentMethodResult.getTarget();
```

However, no word about what valid tokens are in the documentation. Neither [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method-nonce/create/java) nor [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/java#payment_method_token) - or am I just blind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You do not need a `payment_method_token` to create a `PaymentMethod`.

To create a credit card, you will need to create a [PaymentMethod](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/java). First, retrieve the `payment_method_nonce` from the incoming request. Next, create the `PaymentMethod` using `PaymentMethodRequest`.

```java
//payment_method_nonce will be a post parameter in the request
//set nonceFromTheClient to equal payment_method_nonce
PaymentMethodRequest paymentMethodRequest = new PaymentMethodRequest()
            .customerId(customer.getId())
            .paymentMethodNonce(nonceFromTheClient);
Result<? extends PaymentMethod> result = gateway.paymentMethod().create(request);
```

Comment: How can we retrieve the payment_method_nonce?

Comment: can you create a payment nonce in the server side?